# c# console app press spacebar without displaying it on screen

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a real simple cookie clicker using c# console app.
the idea is that everytime you click <kbd>spacebar</kbd> you'll get one cookie (endless)
but my code doesn't work, does anyone know what I did wrong or forgot?

This is my code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cookie = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Coockie Clicker, druk op spatie om te beginnen...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        while (cookie <1000000)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();

        if(Console.ReadLine() == " ")
             {
                 cookie++;
                 Console.WriteLine("Cookies ="+cookie);
             }
            else
            {

            }
        Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
```

what i am expecting to work?= everytime i press spacebar ( if(Console.ReadLine() == " ") <--- that bit over there it should add +1 to int cookie and do this until 1.000.000 but there is clearly something not working

Comment: Using only Console.ReadKey is enough.

Comment: "my code doesnt work" - You have to tell us the expected behavior and what the current behavior is and how it's different than what you need. For a start I'd get rid of the first `Console.ReadLine()` and the last `Console.ReadKey()` inside your while loop.

Comment: In the `if` statement anyway, yes, use ReadKey. ReadLine will wait for a carriage return/line feed before returning

Comment: apparently `infinity = 1000000` here,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cookie = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Coockie Clicker, druk op spatie om te beginnen...");

        Console.Clear();
        while (cookie < 1000000)
        {

            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                cookie++;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Cookies =" + cookie);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The second use of ReadKey should also intercept the value or else the user will see the spaces typed.

Comment: it works, but everytime i press space it adds another cookie on another line in the application but i want to to add a cookie on the same line everytime, how do i do that?

Comment: You want to print it after the while loop or print it on each key press?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check if that what you were looking for.

Comment: basically i want to add a cookie each time the spacebar is lifted up (to prevent holding down the spacebar) and every time i tap spacbar it adds a cookie (which is what i want) but it displays it on the line underneath the other time i tapped spacebar which isnt what i want

Comment: You had to clearly mention that requirement in your question.

Comment: i basically want to remove the ol d display when i tap spacebar but the int cookies keeps memorized so the screen doesnt get filled up with a lot of cookies="1" , cookies="2" etc

Comment: I'm sorry but it is really difficult to get you here. Anyway, I updated my answer just now. Please check it and let me know if it not fulfill your requirement.

Comment: yes it worked indeed, do you know how i can add a+1cookie when the spacebar key is lifted up, so i can prevent people from holding it down. thanks in advance and im sorry if im bad in making things clearly i'm a new user here and have only been coding for a couple of months by now...

Comment: What did you mean by a+1cookie? It's alright and I wish you al the best for your career. :)

Comment: by +1 cookie i meant one more cookie++, but it works now so i dont have any questions anymore. thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply looking to give a cookie per space bar click, then you can use `Console.ReadKey`. There is an overload which takes a boolean indicating whether you want to "intercept" the key press. When you intercept the key press, the value is not shown to the user.

`Console.ReadLine`, on the other hand, only returns a value if you hit return. The value is displayed to the user no matter what.

Here is an updated code sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int cookie = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Coockie Clicker, druk op spatie om te beginnen...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();
    while (cookie <1000000)
    {
        var ch = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if(ch.KeyChar == ' ')
        {
            cookie++;
            Console.WriteLine("Cookies ="+cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to make it endless you should use something like

```
while (true)
```

instead of

```
while (cookie <1000000)
```

but note that although I doubt that you will get more cookies than int.MaxValue but however technically it could overflow.

Secondly `Console.ReadLine()` reads a line so it requires an Enter key at the end, you should just use `Console.ReadKey()`

an the third one is that you have an extra read line:

```
  Console.ReadLine();
  if(Console.ReadLine() == " ")
```

so it expects you enter a line (which you don't use, and just waiting for user to finally click enter) and then you read another line and compare it with `" "`

```
 if(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
 {
      //generate your cookie here
 }
```